# how to separate a digit after semicolon using sscanf in c

Tags: c

//I wanted to separate last digit i.e."2" as an int from "hello.mp4;2" Here is the code:

```
int main()
{

    char str[30];
    int separate = 0;
    strcpy( str, "hello.mp4;2" );
    sscanf(str, "%*[^;]%d", &separate);
    printf("%d\n",separate);
    return 0;

}
```

and it is not woriking...

Comment: use `"%*[^;];%d"` instead of `"%*[^;]%d"`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY - cool, maybe elaborate a bit on what's going on here in that control string; and why there should be two semicolons instead of only one.

Comment: @artm you need the part to read `;` because `^;` isn't read `;`.

Answer (score 2):

Change the `sscanf` to:

```
sscanf(str, "%*[^;];%d", &separate);
```

I.e., you need to match the semicolon `;` after the string that excludes it.  The portion in the square brackets matches the string that precedes the semicolon, leaving `;2`.  So you then need to match the semicolon `;` before trying to match the `2`.